How to properly generate a CMake project for Visual Studio
When I configure the CMake project with the Visual Studio generator it generates the Visual Studio solution. In the solution in the explorer I can see the CMakeLists.txt, and if it changes Visual Studio detects it, and asks to reload the entire solution, so far so good. However it doesn't seem to be a proper CMake solution as you would get if you go to new project and select a new CMake project from Visual Studio itself. A whole bunch options are missing in the context menus when you right click:

"Configure Cache with CMake Debugging" is missing, along with the CMakePresets.json and a whole bunch of other stuff. The problem is I don't know how to get to this stage through CMake. I use the GUI, and I use it to generate the Visual Studio project, which is sort of half working. ie., it detects the CMakeLists.txt and detects changes, so it knows it's CMake solution/project, but it just doesn't have the other stuff. And this means I can't debug the CMakeLists.txt.

Using the visual studio generator essentially means cmake will be generating project and solution files so that visual studio doesn't have to know anything about cmake at all. This was implemented, as part of cmake, before visual studio had any support for cmake [1]
Since then, Visual studio developers have started implementing direct cmake support inside the tool.
In order to get access to that support, the canonical way is to "Open a local Folder" as your project, where the CMakeLists.txt resides. Visual Studio will then configure itself for cmake integration.
More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170
[1] I've not looked at it recently, but I imagine CMakeLists.txt has a special rule in the project to make it re-run cmake on modifications, triggering a regeneration of the project, and therefore a reload from VS. All this so that cmake projects could interact with the VS IDE, when its developers didn't implement first-class support for it.
